# Windows Phone 8.1 build appx file with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I use Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 to build first Windows Phone 8.1 app.
After build, I get appxupload file and appx file.
And after that, I upload file to store, but I get Attention is can't test my app.

So, I use real phone to test with appxupload file and appx file, but 2 file can't install on phone.
And I build app again, I see "the option to create x86 package is disabled because it's not valid package that can be published to the windows phone store".

Do I miss something?
Why appxupload file and appx file can't install on phone?
How to build correct file upload to store?

Comment: The phone is that developer unlocked? Is it s release build of ARM type? The release build results in an appx that you should be able to upload directly on the dev center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I miss something? Why appxupload file and appx file can't install on phone?

For Windows Phone 8.1 app, you could deploy and test your app in Windows Phone Emulator first. While it would be highly recommended to test your app on actual device before you upload it to the Store.

For sideloading Windows  Phone 8.1 app, you could try to use the **Application Deployment tool**:

•   First you have generate your app package

•   Then make sure the device is registered and connected

•   Find the Application Deployment tool in Start menu

•   Run the tool and browse the package file (.appx) then click **deploy**

For details, please refer to [Deploy Windows Phone 8.1 apps with the Application Deployment tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632395.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> How to build correct file upload to store?

To make your app pass the certification, you could re-create your app package following [Create a Windows 8.1 app package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh975357.aspx).

After you finish generating package, please ensure your app pass the [Windows App Certification Kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/app-certification-kit) test first, which is not necessary but a best practice before submitting package to the Store.

It seems that your app fail to pass the certification for “the app must be testable”. You might as well add some [notes for certification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/notes-for-certification) to the tester:

e.g. if your app requires users to sign in to a service, you need to provide a test account in it. This can ensure your app is tested correctly.